# Autoit runas access denied

Tags: autoit

I need to copy a file in  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder using a non-admin user. 
I done a script using autoit and runas function but I receive "access denied"
How can I copy a file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` using a non-admin user account?

Comment: try to add #RequireAdmin to the top of the script

Answer (score -1):

First check that file you copy can be copied with basic batch script.  Sometime overwrite is not possible due ownership rights.

Answer (score -2):

Try that rights elevation code:

```
If Not IsAdmin() Then ;if not admin become admin
    ShellExecute(@AutoItExe, $CmdLineRaw, @WorkingDir , "runas", @SW_SHOWNORMAL) ; "runas" - require admin privileges. i don't now how it works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ magic...
Else ;normal execution if already admin
```